# Why didn't the Borg send a tactical cube the 2nd time?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, borg, star-trek-first-contact

For reference, I am talking about the Battle of Sector 001 in the movie "First Contact."

I can understand that the Borg were busy dealing with species 8472, and that's a reasonable explanation for only sending 1 cube, **but why wasn't a tactical cube sent for the second assault of Earth if a regular one had failed before?** It's not like tactical cubes would have helped them fight against species 8472 anyway.

The 1st cube was nearly unstoppable. And the queen spending resources to create an assimilation virus  shows us that the Borg were still interested in assimilating Earth. The name 'tactical cube' implies this is what that type of cube is designed do to. So instead of possibly wasting another cube the second time, why not send a stronger one?

If you sent a cube that almost worked, wouldn't you send a stronger one the next time?

Comment: the borg didnt really care, the federation was far outside their sphere of influence in the galaxy. they would get to the federation when they got to it, they dont run on human time tables. taking the federation down this week, or in 1000 years doesnt matter to the borg.

Comment: the question is specifically about the 2nd attack, if they were going to send a cube anyway, why not a tactical one if the 1st failed

Comment: It's possible they were just diverting resources that were in the area already. The Borg didn't seem to have the transwarp capabilities we saw in Voyager during their invasions of Earth, or at least the cubes involved didn't. Also possible those cubes were out of date and not worth upgrading, so they were being spent on low priority missions of relatively high risk.

Comment: Could you be a bit clearer about your time lines? are you talking about First Contact? The Battle of Wolf 359? I assume you mean to earth but that is also unclear to me...

Comment: Tactical Cubes are pretty rare. Regular Cubes, on the other hand, are in abundance for the Borg. So I think a better question is, "After one cube failed, why didn't the borg send two? Or 50?"

Comment: My suggestion of a tactical cube was because that ship was important enough for a queen to accompany it personally, which rarely happens. But yeah 2 regular cubes would be an appropriate response to the 1st failed attack and not a big drain on the borg. Repeating a failed attack the same way though just makes no sense

Comment: @Matt I supposed they gathered a lot of data with the first attempt and as that almost succeeded it is likely that the Borg determined with the added tactical knowledge, another regular cube would be sufficient.

Comment: The answer, I believe, is Picard.  The borg were winning that battle.  Against normal fighting techniques of the federation, it can be assumed they would have succeeded.  Picard having memory of the "sweet spot" on the cube for the federation to focus their attack on is what caused them to lose